# Prove $H\circ N = H\cap N$. Where $H$ and $N$ are two subgroups of a group $G$.

Tags: group-theory

I was trying to prove another theorem where I thought the above result could be helpful and started trying to prove it.
I am not sure whether the above statement is true or not, but I am unable to prove it. I'll be very thankful if somebody can help me out.
[NOTE: $H\circ N = \{h\circ n|h\in H, n\in N\}$].

Comment: What is $H \circ N$?

Comment: That is the product of the groups H and N. @Mindlack

Comment: Which product? Is it the set of products $hn \in G$, $h \in H$, $n \in N$? The subgroup spanned by this set? If so, it contains $H \cup N$, so it equals $H \cap N$ iff $H=N$.

Comment: This is not clear.  Surely you can't mean it as stated...what if, say, $H=<e>$ and $N=G$?  Then $H\circ G=G$ but $H\cap G=<e>$.  What did you mean?

Comment: Yes, now I sort of get it. @Mindlack I was talking about the same product as you did. Thanks.

Comment: Doubt cleared @lulu Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @AakashSinghBais You can post an answer to your own question here, and accept it. Please don't just edit the question to include the answer, because the question will remain on the unanswered queue and attract unncecessary attention.

Comment: I think one can't accept their own answers....?! @EthanBolker

Comment: @AakashSinghBais Yes you can, perhaps only after a while. I have.

Comment: Yes, now it is saying I can do it after 2 days. Thanks @EthanBolker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mindlack, the doubt is now clear, and it was very silly.

$H\circ N$ as defined above should contain all elements of $H\cup N$, and only in the case $H=N$, $H\circ N = H\cap N$ is true.

Comment: In fact, the situation is essentially the opposite of what you thought:  $|HN||H\cap N|=|H||N|$, so the larger $|H\cap N|$ is, the smaller $|HN|$ is. (Thinking of $|H|$ and $|N|$ as being fixed.)